# Javascript equivalent for java.lang.Character.getNumericValue(char ch) method

Tags: javascript, java

Javascript's `charCodeAt()` method gives ASCII equivalent value for the characters (like 65 to 90 for 'A' to 'Z'). Is there any Javascript method equivalent for Java's `Character.getNumericValue()` method, which returns `int` value that the specified Unicode character represents? (Eg. It returns 10 to 35 for 'A' to 'Z')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseInt` will do that if you tell it to use base 36:

```js
console.log(parseInt("A", 36)); // 10
console.log(parseInt("Z", 36)); // 35
```

If you want (and you aren't writing a library or module that others will mix into their code), you could even add `getNumericValue` to `String.prototype`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "getNumericValue", {
  value() {
    return parseInt(this, 36);
  },
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});

console.log("A".getNumericValue()); // 10
```

It's best not to extend built-in prototypes when writing libraries or modules that will be mixed into code you don't directly control, since if everyone did it, conflicts can arise. And if extending a built-in prototype, it's important to use `Object.defineProperty` so the property isn't enumerable (the default for `enumerable` is `false`). Even in your own codebase, it's usually best not to extend `Object.prototype` at all (not even with non-enumerable properties).

Comment: The case against extending built-in prototypes also relates to it being really slow compared to the direct procedural approach because the receiver has to be wrapped into an object to make the method call. https://jsperf.com/negative-modulo/2 .Overall, great answer

Comment: @AlmostHandsome - You can prevent that object wrapping and its associated cost by using strict mode when defining the prototype function: https://jsperf.com/negative-modulo/17 (Doesn't matter if it's *called* from loose mode, just matters that it be defined in strict.) In strict mode, it's a dead heat in Chrome and Firefox (looks like Edge still has work to do in that regard, assuming they continue to use Chakra after switching over to Chromium for everything else...). :-) (Not that I'm advocating the prototype approach.)